# Debugger Throwing nullptr Exception During nullptr Check

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, null-pointer

While going through runtime, I'm getting a nullptr exception while this code is executing.

```
bool Tree::Insert(int n)
{
    if (root == nullptr) // This is where it throws
    {
        Node* root = new Node(n);
        return true;
    }
```

Initialization in Tree.h

```
private:
Node* root;
```

and Tree constructor.

```
Tree::Tree()
{
    root = nullptr;
}
```

I have coded exactly like this before and it never threw an exception.

UPDATE:
I apologize for the confusion on the extra '}' Tree::Insert(). There's more code in there and they all have a return case. I had this before

```
Node* newNode = new Node(n);
root = newNode;
```

but changed it for a different reason.

Node.h

```
#pragma once

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    // Constructor
    Node() { data = 0; left = nullptr; right = nullptr; }
    // Parameterized
    Node(int d) { data = d; left = nullptr; right = nullptr; }
    // Destructor
    ~Node() { data = 0; }
};
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not all paths return in `Tree::Insert`, it's undefined behavior

Comment: BTW You're defining a new  `root` variable inside a new Scope, shadowing the class variable.

Comment: Could you provide code Node class also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either access the `Tree::Insert` member directly (i.e. not via an instance of the `Tree` class as if it was a static member) or the instance of the `Tree` class you're using to access the `Insert` method is not initialized.

In other words, `this` is null.

Comment: @TobySpeight, exactly! This is what I was typing when noticed your comment.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. The issue was in my driver. rather then properly initializing it by typing "Tree* Binary_Tree = new Tree;" I instead typed "Tree* Binary_Tree;" Because of this, the constructor wasn't called.

Answer (score -2):

nullptr is implementation-specific. when you say, 
*"I have coded exactly like this before and it never threw an exception."*
you may have to check if it was on a different compiler.

Comment: `nullptr` is not implementation-specific an any meaningful sense here. `nullptr_t::operator==` is fully specified in the standard.